# Android studio git integration working partially

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control

My Android Studio git integration works is some strange way. It is works from main menu, works from *Project pane*. But some important features are disabled at *Version control pane*, e.g. *Show diff* is disabled, *commit* button is absent. What is happened? Has anybody seen such strange behavior and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: It was 1.5 Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio 2.0 totally solved this problem.